# Dropping unused indexes in googleApp

Tags: google-app-engine, indexing

I try to remove unused indexes which I created for some testing purposes before by command `appcfg.sh vacuum_indexes [path_to_app]`. When I run other commands like `update` everything goes fine but this particular command causes following exception:

```
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AdminException: Unable to perform vacuum_indexes
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.vacuumIndexes(AppAdminImpl.java:346)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$VacuumIndexesAction.execute(AppCfg.java:1605)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.executeAction(AppCfg.java:327)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:210)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:121)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:117)
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Line 0, column 12: Unable to find property 'application' on class: com.google.apphosting.utils.config.IndexYamlReader$IndexYaml
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.IndexYamlReader.parseMultiple(IndexYamlReader.java:158)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.IndexDeleter.diffIndexesOnServer(IndexDeleter.java:72)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.IndexDeleter.deleteUnusedIndexes(IndexDeleter.java:186)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.vacuumIndexes(AppAdminImpl.java:342)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.google.appengine.repackaged.net.sourceforge.yamlbeans.YamlReader$YamlReaderException: Line 0, column 12: Unable to find property 'application' on class: com.google.apphosting.utils.config.IndexYamlReader$IndexYaml
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.net.sourceforge.yamlbeans.YamlReader.readValueInternal(YamlReader.java:259)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.net.sourceforge.yamlbeans.YamlReader.readValue(YamlReader.java:150)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.net.sourceforge.yamlbeans.YamlReader.read(YamlReader.java:106)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.net.sourceforge.yamlbeans.YamlReader.read(YamlReader.java:91)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.IndexYamlReader.parseMultiple(IndexYamlReader.java:203)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.IndexYamlReader.parseMultiple(IndexYamlReader.java:156)
    ... 8 more
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

That's a known problem on our end that we're working to get resolved. Stay tuned.